# JQuery Ajax Script working on Local Machine but not on Server

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, file

I've exhaustively looked through the internet to find a solution for this problem. 
So I have a jquery ajax script that loads in a csv file and generates some html code incorporating the data in the csv file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({

       type: "GET",
       url: "database.csv",
       dataType: "html",
       data: {},
       success: function(text) {
           // Location of key information
           var nameLoc;
           var siteLoc;
           var typeLoc;
           var categoryLoc;
           var descripLoc;
           var canRequestLoc;
           var EClassLoc;
           var description='';
           var temp = "Y";
           var charTemp;
           var site;
           var len;
           var fields = text.split(/\n/);
           fields.pop(fields.length-1);

           var headers = fields[0].split(','), html = '<table align="center" id="searchData">';

           for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i += 1) {
              switch (headers[i]){
                case 'Name':
                    nameLoc = i;
                 break;
                case 'RequestSystem':
                    siteLoc = i;
                break;
                case 'Type':
                    typeLoc = i;
                break;
                case 'Category':
                    categoryLoc = i;
                break;
                case 'canRequest':
                    canRequestLoc = i;
                break;
                case 'ECAPSClassification':
                    EClassLoc = i;
                break;
                case 'Description':
                    descripLoc = i;
                break;
              };
           }
           descripLoc = canRequestLoc + 2;

           var data = fields.slice(1, fields.length);

           for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j += 1) {

              var dataFields = data[j].split(',');
              if (dataFields[nameLoc]==0){
                html += '</table>';
                $(html).appendTo('body');
                break;
              };

              html += '<tr>';
              html += '<td class="demo-show"> <h3>' + dataFields[nameLoc] +  '</h3>';
              html += '<div class="menuBar"> ';

              charTemp = dataFields[canRequestLoc];
              if (charTemp=='Y'){
                switch (dataFields[siteLoc]){
                    case 'Service Now':
                        site = 'https://ccsn.service-now.com/'; 
                        break;
                    case 'CCR IdM':
                        site = 'http://idm.na.cokecce.com'; 
                        break;
                    case 'ECAPS':
                        site = 'https://ecaps.cokeccr.com/ecaps';   
                        break;
                    case 'KO IdM':
                        site = 'https://apps.ko.com/idm';   
                        break;
                    default:
                        site = 'default';   
                        break;
                };
                html += '<a href="' + site + '">' + 'Request Access' + '</a><br>';
              }
              else{
                html += '<br><b> ' + dataFields[canRequestLoc+1] + '</b> <br> <br>';
              };
              html += '<b>Request System: </b>' + dataFields[siteLoc] + '<br>';
              if (dataFields[siteLoc]=='ECAPS'){
                html += '<b>ECAPS Classification: </b>' + dataFields[EClassLoc] + '<br>';
              };
              html += '<b>Type: </b>' + dataFields[typeLoc] + '<br>';
              html += '<b>Category: </b>' + dataFields[categoryLoc] + '<br>';

               html += '<b>Description: </b> ' ;

              for (var k=descripLoc; k<dataFields.length; k+=1){
                 html += dataFields[k];
              }

               html += '<br><br></div>';
              html += '</td> </tr>';

           }
           html += '</table>';
           $('.app').append(html);
       }        
    });
});
</script>
```

So the script loads all the information perfectly but the part

```
html += '<td class="demo-show"> <h3>' + dataFields[nameLoc] +  '</h3>';
```

class="demo-show" is supposed to link this to another script where it makes the information between below the  hidden. Like an accordion.

The script for that is (at different part of document):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.demo-show > div').hide();  
    $('td.demo-show > h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

All of this works in my local machine but when I put it on the server the accordion script doesn't work which is weird because the exact same script is used in another part of the site and it works.

Only the part loaded by the JQuery Ajax part doesn't work.

I've tried everything!! This is my first time ever posting on a forum.
Please take a look and let me know what you think.

UPDATE: 
Here is the site. Please try it in IE
http://jsolomon9.99k.org/

The part that's not working is that when you click on "Heading 1" the information below it should also do the accordion effect. Instead it is just static.

Comment: how is it not working?  Is the server getting the request?  Is there an http error?  A javascript error?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. I know its not working because the jquery accordion isn't working

Comment: in chrome there is no content inside heading1

Comment: Yea for some reason when I was removing the content it stopped working on FF and Chrome. I only need it to run on IE. Could you try it with that

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your source and here are the js files you added

```
<script src="files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="files/more-show.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you should not add two jquery files instead get rid of `files/jquery.js` and move `files/jquery.min.js` to the top of your page. like this and then try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/more-show.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I just tried that, didn't work. I updated the html with the change

Comment: try using this link for your jQuery https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js u are using On and u need latest version of jQuery

Comment: Thanks! that plus changing the script to use .on helped! Thanks!!